# Context-Free Grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar

I need help understanding this concept.

The book states

```
G1:
    A→0A1
    A→B
    B→#
```

it states that `G1` generates the string `000#111`

and shows a process

```
A → 0A1 → 00A11 → 000A111 → 000B111 → 000#111
```

I understand what is happening in here. What I'm unsure of is if it can be infinitely looped.

For example:

can `G1` also generate `0#1` using this process

```
A → 0A1 → 0B1 → 0#1
```

The book doesn't explain this part as clearly. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, any production can be applied an infinite number of times, thereby generating (in this and in most cases) an infinite number of strings.
This grammar generates all strings of the form 0<sup>n</sup>#1<sup>n</sup>

Comment: I appreciate it. It actually did end up saying in the book but a couple pages after a few examples they gave. They formalized the definition. Thanks alot.

Comment: @juice yes do you notice `A → 0A1` here `A` can be replaced in RHS by itself production this rule make it to produce infinitely large 0^n_1^n,  `A --> B` is included to convert the sentimental form into sentence. You can rewite same grammar like `A --> 0A1 | #`

Answer (score 0):

Yes surely. The given grammar also generates the `0#1` language. The thing is clear enough. As you can see , the generated language 0#1 is a subset of the former language generated by the same grammar.